# Matlab command window tabs (tabbed)

Tags: linux, matlab, unix

Hi I hope this question conforms to community guidelines. While working in Matlab I'd really appreciate if the command window had tabs (much like most terminal emulators in Linux). Is available in Matlab or do I have to run different instances of Matlab?

I am running a system which produces plots so running Matlab in text based mode via -nojvm is not possible.

EDIT: Is there a way to get such a feature or do I have to wait for Mathworks to wake up and implement this simple, timesaving tool.

Hmm I think the way Matlab works (with the workspace and the editor) tabs might not be that beneficial in terms of performance as opposed to just running a new instance of Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux, you can fork new MATLAB instances with `unix` command and pass the MATLAB command you want to run as a command line argument. If you add `&` to the end of the `unix` input string, the new MATLAB instance becomes a background process, so this way from one MATLAB command window you can run commands (with output) in several MATLAB instances, opening a new MATLAB instance for command execution and output.

Here's the code:

multithread.m:

```
function multithread(MatlabCommand)
% this is a function to create a new MATLAB instance and run a command in it.
unix([ 'matlab -desktop -r ', MatlabCommand, ' &' ]);
return
```

testfunction.m:

```
function testfunction()
fprintf('one two three.\n');
return
```

Then you can run MATLAB commands in a new instance this way: `multithread('testfunction');`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such feature.

Although are you aware that you can use the `-nodesktop` flag to run Matlab in the current console and still have the ability to bring up plots?

Answer (score 0):

Well - depends on what you plan to do with the tabs. You do have tabs for file editor, variable editor. But I suppose you mean command window.

I sometimes have two or more instances of Matlab open - one doing some calculation and doing some observation and quick stuff from the other - but I don't find it advisable.

I have found against using multiple instances that the preferences and path get "unusable" regularly (say once every month).

But as Matlab is "single" threaded - while it's calculating it's near impossible to do simple tasks as editing code or open a file in the same instance. If it had tabs i imagine it even worse. I think this problems lie very deep inside how Matlab works so that will not change very soon.